# How to make it obvious if a window has focus in Windows 11?

Tags: google-chrome, colors, windows-11

It used to be that windows had title bars, and the window's title bar indicated very obviously whether that window had focus, using the "accent color" and also by making the title bold.

Unfortunately, Microsoft has over time taken that away and also taken away customizability. Is there any fix?

What I mean:
[image: screenshot of Settings/Personalization/Colors with Show accent color on title bars and window borders set to On]

When you enable this option (why isn't it on by default? why would I *not* want to know what window is active?), **nothing** actually changes for **this very window**, if it is maximized. (If not, you get a tiny visible border around it.)

For old-school apps like Total Commander, it works. Active window with accent color enabled (what I want):

[image]

Inactive window:

[image]

Active window *without* the accent color option enabled:

[image]

I suspect there isn't a system-wide fix for this -- the apps with this bug/problem (which ironically includes Windows' own settings app) are, I'm guessing, drawing their own title bar, if any, and so are free to ignore the system setting, am I right?

If there isn't a system-wide fix for this, is there one for Brave (or for Chrome, which then might be applicable to Brave)? I have discovered this in chrome://flags but it doesn't seem to work:

[image: #pervasive-system-accent-color]

Comment: This should have worked. Have you chosen blue under "Personalization > Colors"? Check also in `regedit` key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorPrevalence` the contents of the item `AccentColor`.

Comment: This has been a bugbear of mine since the very first win10. Whoever made this design decision should have been fired.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, blue is selected. ColorPrevalence=1, AccentColor=ffd47800. I also tried setting EnableWindowColorization to 1, no obvious effect. I think it's working as designed, it's just horrible design. Does it accent the title bar for you? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: My registry settings are the same and it's working fine for me. I can give an example for any standard Windows application that you wish, but note that I'm on Windows 10. Windows 11 is still too buggy for me.

Comment: Microsoft has a Title Bar color system.  Start, Settings, Personalization, Colors, Accent Color.  It often works for 3rd party apps and Microsoft Office. But Microsoft has written off this useful feature and is not using it for Explorer, Notepad or other Microsoft Apps. They are trying to make certain you cannot use Windows effectively.

Comment: @John Doesn't seem to work for (current) Office apps unfortunately, either. Unless there is some option buried somewhere that enables it.